# bibliography splits across columns and pages

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, ieeetran

I have this bibliography below a nice long table which is the appendix as in the image below. 
 The problem is that a single ciation splits across columns and pages. I wonder if this is normal? 
 I checked many papers and they have like more than 300 citaions but didn't have this problem.
If I want to fix this, is there any method? 
In section XIV of [this](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) document, they mentioned about `\IEEEtriggeratref{}`. However, this only work if I use one time like `\IEEEtriggeratref{9}` which would move the `ref[9]` to the new column. If I used both `\IEEEtriggeratref{9} \IEEEtriggeratref{19}` in two lines then only `\IEEEtriggeratref{19}` effects the result.

**In summary I have two questions:**

1. Is it normal and okay to split citations across columns and pages like that? I have checked many articles in the field but didn't found any.
2. How can I fix that? Above I mentioned about `\IEEEtriggeratref{}`but it seems like it only works partially as I can't use it for two or more places of splitted citations.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
  @article{Junginger:10,
  author = {F. Junginger and A. Sell and O. Schubert and B. Mayer and D. Brida and M. Marangoni and G. Cerullo and A. Leitenstorfer and R. Huber},
  journal = {Optics Letters},
  number = {15},
  pages = {2645--2647},
  publisher = {OSA},
  title = {Single-cycle multiterahertz transients with peak fields above 10 {MV}/cm},
  volume = {35},
  month = {Aug},
  year = {2010},
  url = {http://ol.osa.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ol-35-15-2645},
  doi = {10.1364/OL.35.002645},
  }
  @article{IEEEexample:bluebookarticle,
  author        = "{Consulative Committee for Space Data Systems (CCSDS)}",
  title         = "Telemetry Channel Coding",
  journal       = "Blue Book",
  number        = "4",
  year          = "1999",
  url           = "http://www.ccsds.org/documents/pdf/CCSDS-101.0-B-4.pdf"
}
  @book{IEEEexample:bluebookbook,
  author        = "{Consulative Committee for Space Data Systems (CCSDS)}",
  title         = "Telemetry Channel Coding",
  series        = "Blue Book",
  number        = "4",
  publisher     = "{CCSDS}",
  address       = "Newport Beach, {CA}",
  year          = "1999",
  url           = "http://www.ccsds.org/documents/pdf/CCSDS-101.0-B-4.pdf"
}
  @article{LPOR:LPOR201000013,
  author = {Cerullo, G. and Baltu{\v s}ka, A. and M{\"u}cke, O.D. and Vozzi, C.},
  title = {Few-optical-cycle light pulses with passive carrier-envelope phase stabilization},
  journal = {Laser \& Photonics Reviews},
  volume = {5},
  number = {3},
  publisher = {WILEY-VCH Verlag},
  issn = {1863-8899},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/lpor.201000013},
  doi = {10.1002/lpor.201000013},
  pages = {323--351},
  year = {2011},
  }
  @electronic{IEEEexample:shellCTANpage,
  author        = "Michael Shell",
  title         = "{IEEE}tran Webpage on {CTAN}",
  url           = "http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran",
  year          = "2015"
}
@electronic{IEEEexample:IEEEwebsite,
  title         = "The {IEEE} Website",
  url           = "http://www.ieee.org/",
  year          = "2015",
  key           = "IEEE"
}
@article{IEEEexample:article_typical,
  author        = "S. Zhang and C. Zhu and J. K. O. Sin and P. K. T. Mok",
  title         = "A Novel Ultrathin Elevated Channel Low-temperature 
                   Poly-{Si} {TFT}",
  journal       = IEEE_J_EDL,
  volume        = "20",
  month         = nov,
  year          = "1999",
  pages         = "569-571"
}
@article{IEEEexample:articleetal,
  author        = "F. Delorme and others",
  title         = "Butt-jointed {DBR} Laser With 15 {nm} Tunability Grown
                   in Three {MOVPE} Steps",
  journal       = "Electron. Lett.",
  volume        = "31",
  number        = "15",
  year          = "1995",
  pages         = "1244-1245"
}
  @inproceedings{Kanuparthy:2011:SED:2068816.2068860,
  author = {Partha Kanuparthy and Constantine Dovrolis},
  title = {ShaperProbe: end-to-end detection of ISP traffic shaping using active methods},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2011 ACM SIGCOMM conference on Internet measurement conference},
  series = {IMC '11},
  year = {2011},
  isbn = {978-1-4503-1013-0},
  location = {Berlin, Germany},
  pages = {473--482},
  numpages = {10},
  url = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/2068816.2068860},
  doi = {10.1145/2068816.2068860},
  acmid = {2068860},
  publisher = {ACM},
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  keywords = {active probing, inference, traffic shaping},
  }
  @inproceedings{soule2004flow,
  title={Flow classification by histograms: or how to go on safari in the internet},
  author={Augustin Soule and Kav{\'e} Salamatia and Nina Taft and Richard Emilion and Konstantina Papagiannaki},
  booktitle={ACM SIGMETRICS Performance Evaluation Review},
  volume={32},
  number={1},
  pages={49--60},
  year={2004},
  organization={ACM}
  }
  @book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
  }

  @book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
  and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
  }

  @book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{\LaTeX}: a Document Preparation System},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
  }

  @article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
  }
@electronic{IEEEhowto:IEEEtranpage,
  author        = "Michael Shell",
  title         = "{IEEE}tran Homepage",
  url           = "http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/",
  year          = "2015"
}
  @inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title={Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author={Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of American Federation of
  Information Processing Societies: 1977
  National Computer Conference},
  pages={879--888},
  year={1977},
  address={Dallas, Texas}
  }
  @article{Khoe:1994:CML:2288694.2294265,
  author = {Khoe, G. -D.},
  title = {Coherent multicarrier lightwave technology for flexible capacity networks},
  journal = {Comm. Mag.},
  issue_date = {March 1994},
  volume = {32},
  number = {3},
  month = mar,
  year = {1994},
  issn = {0163-6804},
  pages = {22--33},
  numpages = {12},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/35.267438},
  doi = {10.1109/35.267438},
  acmid = {2294265},
  publisher = {IEEE Press},
  address = {Piscataway, NJ, USA},
  }
  @inproceedings{IEEEexample:conf_typical,
  author        = "R. K. Gupta and S. D. Senturia",
  title         = "Pull-in Time Dynamics as a Measure of Absolute Pressure",
  booktitle     = "Proc. {IEEE} International Workshop on
                   Microelectromechanical Systems ({MEMS}'97)",
  address       = "Nagoya, Japan",
  month         = jan,
  year          = "1997",
  pages         = "290-294"
}
@electronic{IEEEexample:electronorgadd,
  author        = "D. H. Lorenz and A. Orda",
  title         = "Optimal Partition of {QoS} Requirements on Unicast
                   Paths and Multicast Trees",
  organization  = "Dept. Elect. Eng., Technion",
  address       = "Haifa, Israel",
  url           = "ftp://ftp.technion.ac.il/pub/supported/ee/Network/lor.mopq98.ps",
  month         = jul,
  year          = "1998"
}
@misc{IEEEexample:miscrfc,
  author        = "K. K. Ramakrishnan and S. Floyd",
  title         = "A Proposal to Add Explicit Congestion
                   Notification ({ECN}) to {IP}",
  howpublished  = "RFC 2481",
  month         = jan,
  year          = "1999"
}
@book{IEEEexample:book_typical,
  author        = "B. D. Cullity",
  title         = "Introduction to Magnetic Materials",
  publisher     = "Addison-Wesley",
  address       = "Reading, MA",
  year          = "1972"
}
@incollection{IEEEexample:incollection_chpp,
  author        = "P. Hedelin and P. Knagenhjelm and M. Skoglund",
  editor        = "W. B. Kleijn and K. K. Paliwal",
  title         = "Theory for Transmission of Vector Quantization Data",
  booktitle     = "Speech Coding and Synthesis",
  publisher     = "Elsevier Science",
  address       = "Amsterdam, The Netherlands",
  year          = "1995",
  chapter       = "10",
  pages         = "347-396"
}
@article{IEEEexample:TBParticle,
  author        = "N. Kahale and R. Urbanke",
  title         = "On the Minimum Distance of Parallel and Serially
                   Concatenated Codes",
  journal       = IEEE_J_IT,
  year          = "submitted for publication"
}
@misc{IEEEexample:TBPmisc,
  author        = "M. Coates and A. Hero and R. Nowak and B. Yu",
  title         = "Internet Tomography",
  howpublished  = IEEE_M_SP,
  month         = may,
  year          = "2002",
  note          = "to be published"
}
@article{IEEEexample:articlelargepages,
  author        = "A. Castaldini and A. Cavallini and B. Fraboni
                   and P. Fernandez and J. Piqueras",
  title         = "Midgap Traps Related to Compensation Processes in
                   {CdTe} Alloys",
  journal       = "Phys. Rev. B.",
  volume        = "56",
  number        = "23",
  year          = "1997",
  pages         = "14897-14900"
}
@article{IEEEexample:articledualmonths,
  author        = "Y. Okada and K. Dejima and T. Ohishi",
  title         = "Analysis and Comparison of {PM} Synchronous Motor and
                   Induction Motor Type Magnetic Bearings",
  journal       = IEEE_J_IA,
  volume        = "31",
  month         = sep # "/" # oct,
  year          = "1995",
  pages         = "1047-1053"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}


\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Example}\label{tab:example}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    X & Y & Z \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\appendix
\raggedbottom

\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\onecolumn
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Table with images},
  label = {tab:image},
]{
  hlines, vlines,
  colsep=3pt,
  colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  rowsep = 3pt,
  rowhead = 1,
}

  No &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
  1  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  2  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  3  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  4  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  5  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  6  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  7  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
  8  & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
     & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{longtblr}
%\IEEEtriggeratref{7}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{reference}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,jobname.bib}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second question:

You can prevent all line breaks in bibliography entries by setting the penalty for a page break within a paragraph to 10000, because every entry is one paragraph. To smuggle this extra penalty into the bibliography only, insert one line near the end of your document as follows:

```tex
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{reference}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \def\BIBdecl{\interlinepenalty=10000 } % insert this line
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,jobname.bib}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, where should I insert the commands? I put it in the preamble and got the error of `LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document` and put it elsewhere gave many errors.

Comment: I have made my answer more explicit.

Comment: It works. I'm curious if people usually do it or not to ensure the bibliography not split. I have checked many articles but didn't see this issue so I wonder if they have naturally not splitted or just use some method to prevent that.

Comment: The relevant command is `\interlinepenalty=10000`.  It should be placed just at the beginning of the bibliography.  One use of `\interlinepenalty`, according to the TeXbook, is to help prevent long footnotes being broken between pages.